# WordPress send email on add_post_meta

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to send a notification email to Author when a Custom Meta Field is added to their WordPress Post by **add_post_meta** or **update_post_meta**.

So far my code below is working successfully but it executes only when I use **Save Post**

```
function order_update_send_email( $post_id ) {

$email_sent = get_post_meta($post_id, 'email_sent', true);
$report = get_post_meta($post_id, 'report', true);

if ( $email_sent == 'Sent' ) {
    return;
}
if ( $report ) {
$post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
$post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
$subject = 'Your report for: ' . $post_title;

$message = "Your order is completed\n\n";
$message .= "Report for: " . $post_title . "\n\n Link:" . $post_url;
$message .= "\n\n" . $report;

wp_mail( 'test@email.me', $subject, $message );
update_post_meta($post_id, 'email_sent', 'Sent');
}
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'order_update_send_email' );
```

In above code the Action hook **save_post** is working fine but I can't get **add_post_meta** or **update_post_meta** to work.

Anyone please advice, thanks.

Comment: Sorry their is no way. Because after update_post_meta and add_post_meta has no action after/before in wordpress. You have to edit the wordpress core to create a action.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below sample code for this.

```
add_action( 'added_post_meta', 'wp_afterpostmeta', 10, 4 );
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'wp_afterpostmeta', 10, 4 );
function wp_afterpostmeta( $meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value )
{
    if ( 'wp_meta_key' == $meta_key ) {
        wp_do_something( $post_id, $meta_value );
    }
}
```